# How to check: variable of function is it path to a folder or file on a remote server?

Tags: command-line-interface, rsync, shell, scp, copy

I need to use `rsync` or `scp` for copy file or file folder from remote server to computer.

To copy (synchronize) a file folder I use the following function:

```
foldertocomp() {
   rsync -avz pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'"/* "/home/comp/Torrent/$1"
}
```

I can use the following functions to copy a file:

```
filetocomp() {
   rsync -avz pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'" "/home/comp/Torrent/"
}
```

OR

```
filetocomp() {
   scp pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'" /home/comp/Torrent
}
```

All these functions work well. But I need to combine these functions into one single function. Like this:

```
tocomp() {
   Some code...
}
```

Use function:

```
tocomp "HERE name of folder OR name of file"
```

I think I need to build the function like this:

```
tocomp() {
   if "$1 is a FILE"
      rsync -avz pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'" "/home/comp/Torrent/"
   elif "$1 is a FOLDER"
      rsync -avz pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'"/* "/home/comp/Torrent/$1"
   fi
}
```

But how to check `$1` is a folder or file?

I found the following method: [stackoverflow.com/a/4665080/10728472](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665080/10728472).
But I think this method not for remote server.

How to check `$1` is a folder or file on a remote server?

Comment: I think if you just add `-r`, you'll be covered for both cases:  `scp -r pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'" /home/comp/Torrent`

Comment: Im with glenn, but in any case if you sync local with remote why you need check if is dir or not in remote I sume is the same content and if is dir in local is also dir in remote, in any case if you want test if is dir in remote you need a new script, connect to remote server over ssh and test if is dir or not.

Comment: To Glenn Jackman: Yes, I previously used this method. But scp does not know how to synchronize (using scp you can not interrupt copying files in a folder and then continue) files in the folder, so I abandoned this method. I apologize for not writing about it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rsync command to sync the directory

```
rsync -avz pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'"/* "/home/comp/Torrent/$1"
```

can be written as

```
rsync -avz pi@192.168.1.5:"'/home/pi/Torrents/$1'" "/home/comp/Torrent/"
```

Both sync directory `$1` to `/home/comp/Torrent/$1`. So you'll only need one command, it's the same as your rsync command for the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat` command on the remote host as shown below to check for the type. You may need to adjust `stat` arguments depending on your remote OS. This should work fine on any Linux flavor.

```
arg="/home/pi/Torrents/$1"

file_or_directory=`ssh pi@192.168.1.5 "stat --format=%F $arg" 2>&1`

if [ "$file_or_directory" = "directory" ] ; then
  echo "$arg: is a directory"
elif [ "$file_or_directory" = "regular file" ] ; then
  echo "$arg: is a file"
elif [ "$file_or_directory" = "symbolic link" ] ; then
  echo "$arg: is a link"
else
  echo "$arg: unknown"
fi
```